# Geometry field name for sld filter

Tags: geometry, openlayers, geoserver, sld

I have a map with some layers based on database table.
I am using OpenLayers + Geoserver, how can I know the name of geomerty field?
Thank you
bye
stefano

UPDATE: I forgot to say that I need to have this information using javascript (API or REST call).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Geoserver and from the Data Menu select Layers.

From the list of layers displayed select the layer you are interested in by clicking no the Layer Name.

On the page that is displayed you should see an area down the bottom called "Feature Type Details" with a list of all the fields in the table associated with that layer. Go down the Type column until you see the type set as Geometry. (Note it is possible to have more than one Geometry field in a table)

Any Property with a type Geometry is a geometry field. The name of the Geometry field is in the associated "Property" column.

If you need to specify what geometry column to use (because there is more than one geometry column ect) you can do something like the following example in your sld filter. Modify to suit your symbolizer or query.

```
<LineSymbolizer>
      <Geometry>
       <ogc:PropertyName>geometry_column_name</ogc:PropertyName>
      </Geometry>            
     </LineSymbolizer>
```

I hope that steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Darkcylde,sorry in my message I forgot to say that I need to have this information using javascript (API or REST call).

Comment: For what purpose do you need to know the goemetry field name. The geometry data will be available if you request the layer by wfs rather than wms. This can be added to your map and the geometry will be availble in the openlayers feature object.

Comment: I need it because I have a WMS layer and I have to clone it applying a SLD style in order to highlight some features. So I would need to know the geometry field because I would like to create SLD dinamically

Comment: WMS doesn't feed you geometry it feeds you tiles. Basically a bunch of images. You then do a get info request for information about a particualr feature. For selecting and hilghlighting particular geometries and features you could look at WFS. Geoserver will let you get a vector layer (instead of tiles) by WFS and do styling on it. If you are highlighting on any value other than a geometry this can also still be accomplished in WMS.